# ConsoleLauncher returns 0 although class-under-test could not be loaded

Tags: junit, junit5

We run a set of tests in a CI pipeline and call our test classes like this:

```
java -classpath junit-jupiter-api-5.0.1.jar:junit-platform-console-standalone-1.0.1.jar org.junit.platform.console.ConsoleLauncher --select-class xy.Test
```

If class `xy.Test` cannot be found on the classpath an error message appears but `ConsoleLauncher`'s return value is **0**! Since our CI system runs unattended the return value is the only important return value! 
As I have seen this behaviour got updated in [JUnit 5.0.0 M2](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#release-notes-5.0.0-m2) but I regard this as I mistake: If I define a class by `--select-class` and the class cannot be found then something has gone wrong!

As I countermeasure I hacked (by means of introspection) `org.junit.platform.commons.util.BlacklistedExceptions` by overwriting blacklist's field with `OutOfMemoryError` (=default) and `PreconditionViolationException` (=case where class could not be found).

(If the standard behaviour shall not be changed...) **I think there should be a better way to get this behaviour!**

Comment: Please open an issue on GitHub to continue the discussion: https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/new

Comment: see on [GitHub](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1298)